# Laravel Storage::extend not working

Tags: php, laravel, dropbox, service-provider, laravel-storage

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, with this. I've followed the Laravel docs by installing `spatie/flysystem-dropbox` via composer copied the DropboxServiceProvider from the Laravel Docs, added the service provided to the `config\app.php`, ran `composer dump autoload` but yet I am still getting the following error message:

```
PHP error:  Undefined index: driver in /***/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php on line 112
```

Here is the service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Storage;
use League\Flysystem\Filesystem;
use Spatie\Dropbox\Client as DropboxClient;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Spatie\FlysystemDropbox\DropboxAdapter;

class DropboxServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Storage::extend('dropbox', function ($app, $config) {
            $client = new DropboxClient(
                $config['authorizationToken']
            );

            return new Filesystem(new DropboxAdapter($client));
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And here's my config/app/php:

```
...
        /*
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\DropboxServiceProvider::class,
        // App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,
        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,

...
```

Finally, here's my config/filesystems.php:

```
'dropbox'=>[
            'authorizationToken'=>env('DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN')
        ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I was missing the driver value in the `config/filesystems/php` so it should have been this:

```
'dropbox'=>[
            'driver' => 'dropbox',  <=== THIS WAS MISSING
            'authorizationToken'=>env('DROPBOX_TOKEN')
        ],
```

Answer (score 0):

One good Pacakge avilable for extend storage using dropbox:
    detail documentation : https://github.com/GrahamCampbell/Laravel-Dropbox

```
steps for use this package :
1 : composer require graham-campbell/dropbox in your cmd window
2 : after this you have to register service provider for laravel dropbox,
    go to config/app.php
    and add 'GrahamCampbell\Dropbox\DropboxServiceProvider' this in provider array
    and 'Dropbox' => 'GrahamCampbell\Dropbox\Facades\Dropbox' this to aliases array
3: now you have to publish pacakge so 'php artisan vendor:publish' run this in your cmd
    - this will create dropbox.php file in your config in this file you have to add your credentials
4: here you have two option for connection you can use it according to your choice.

usage : 
simple example : 
use GrahamCampbell\Dropbox\Facades\Dropbox;
// you can alias this in config/app.php if you like

Dropbox::createFolder('Folder_Name');
// we're done here - how easy was that, it just works!

Dropbox::delete('Folder_Name');
// this example is simple, and there are far more methods available
```